# What is this member function declaration?

Tags: c++, function, operators

I just found this in a code. I have never seen it and really tripped me. I think that the functionality is very obvious, but I would like to know how is it called or something like this? 
It is declared inside a class declaration.

```
auto velFun(double time, double amplitude) -> double
{
  double pi{3.14159};
  return amplitude * sin(4 * pi * time);
};
```

Comment: Does you about -> double ? If yes it is call trailing.

Comment: Is it the trailing return type that's throwing you off or something else? It's really hard to tell from your question what *exactly* you don't understand.

Comment: @JesperJuhl yes, sorry...what is this exactly, what is this functionality for "trailing return", and why use it instead of declaring a double return type ( and a casting to double, if necessary)

Comment: @dasfex, yes mate, what is it exactly. when is it used?

Comment: The linked duplicate should answer that.

Comment: @JesperJuhl The answer at the link is ambiguos. It introduces a new functionality "decltype". What I understood from it, is that it lets you predefine a return type, but you can do this with a static_cast or an implicit casting...whats the core use for this  so-called trailing return?

Comment: @learning_dude, from my point of view it is just other way to specify return type. Sometimes just for readability when you have few function declarations and want them to aligned.